# Whats the best way to generate large amounts of unique promo codes?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am trying to create promo codes in large batches (with php/mysql).

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
$CurrentCodesInMyDB = "asdfasdf,asdfsdfx"; // this is a giant comma delimited string of the current promo codes in the database.
$PromoCodes = "";
for($i=0;$i<=30000;$i++)
{
    $NewCode = GetNewCode($PromoCodes, $CurrentCodesInMyDB );
    $PromoCodes .= $NewCode . ","; //this string gets used to allow them to download a txt file
    //insert $newcode into database here
}

function GetNewCode($CurrentList, $ExistingList)
{
    $NewPromo = GetRandomString();
     if(strpos($CurrentList, $NewPromo) === false && strpos($ExistingList, $NewPromo) === false)
     {
          return $NewPromo; 
     }  
     else
     {
          return GetNewCode($CurrentList, $ExistingList);   
     }
}

function GetRandomString()
{
     return "xc34cv87"; //some random 8 character alphanumeric string
}
```

When I do batches in 10k, it seems to be ok. But the client would like to be able to generate 30k at a time. When I bump the loop up to 30k, I've been having issues. Are there any obvious performance tweaks that I could make or maybe a different way I could do this?

Comment: What kind of "issues" have you been having?

Comment: Why are you storing your codes in a giant string, instead of an array?

Comment: The codes are stored in a table with indexes. I was keeping the list in memory so that I could write a comma delimited list to a text file.

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't need to have all 30,000 codes loaded into memory in a single giant string. Just create a table in your database, add a `code` unique field (either primary key or unique index) and insert random codes until you have 30,000 successful insertions.

Comment: 30000 inserts are expensive as well not to mention relying on insertion fails for flow control

Comment: This was my initial concern, which is why I went with comparing in memory. I am going to try both ways. Thanks

Comment: Try my suggestion bellow check the link and let me know how you go

Comment: @Luis You are assuming that codes do not need to stored. There's no point in generating a random code if you are not going to check it back when used.

Comment: No I am just saying you don't need 500 failed insert operations before storing your codes also developing code that relies on exceptions is bad. On database exceptions is terribly bad

Comment: @Luis 500 is like a 1,6% of 30,000. If you have such collision probability, you need to improve your random-code algorithm or users will be able to generate their own valid codes. And, what about some years later, when there are 10,000,000 legacy codes that cannot be repeated? Load them all into memory or write an ugly hack just to avoid using a native DBMS feature?

Comment: An ugly hack in my opinion is relying on a Database Exception. Exceptions should be used for connection timeouts, or any other event out of the developer control, not for events that are expected and can be handled normally inside your code domain. In some years were going to be swimming in RAM :)

Comment: @Luis yet after 7 years, we're swimming in RAM but more so, we're swimming in data! :D

Answer (score 2):

What kind of issues specifically?

My advice is: don't store the codes in a a CSV format, instead create a new indexed column and store each code on its own row - also, use prepared queries.

Doing 60,000 `strpos()` on a ~250 KB string might not be the best idea ever...

Comment: I'm not really sure to be honest, the first time my computer froze up when the script was running. The second time it finished like 22k of the 30k and then the page stopped rendering.  I think I will take out those strings in memory

Comment: @salietata: You're not sure of...? Try using `set_time_limit(0);` and `ignore_user_abort(true);`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do inserts inside the loop.(they are also expensive) use an array and the method in_array to check for the string. Look in the comments for the in_array function there is someone saying that you can achieve better performance using array_flip and then checking for the array key

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#96198

Comment: No need for `array_flip()`, simply define the value and the key (or just the key) as having the same value and use `isset($arr[$code])`, but then you have the problem of making sure code are unique / not overwritten.

Comment: If you set the key and the value aren't you doubling the amount of memory needed to store the array?

Comment: That's why I said "or just the key". =)